# How to display 3 random values from MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, random

How would I go about displaying 3 random values each time a page is loaded? At the minute I have it displaying one at a time using the following code:

```
<?php
$sSQLQuery = "SELECT careername FROM careers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
$aResult = mysql_query($sSQLQuery);  
$aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);  
$sQuoteOfTheDay = $aRow['careername']; 
echo $sQuoteOfTheDay;   
?>
```

I have tried doing LIMIT 5 but that had no effect on the result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` again for every single record your are fetching.

So, use `LIMIT 3` and then simply loop through the result set. Like this:

```
$sSQLQuery = "SELECT careername FROM careers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";  
$aResult = mysql_query($sSQLQuery);  
while($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $sQuoteOfTheDay = $aRow['careername']; 
    echo $sQuoteOfTheDay; 
}
```

Refer to the manual page of [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). You'll find more examples there.

Comment: You are welcome! ;) .. Further note that the mysql_* extension has been marked deprecated by the PHP developers. So you are not adviced to use this functions in your code. You should look for the alternatives which are [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Change your `LIMIT` to '3' and then loop through all of the results:

```
while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $aRow['careername']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall change the `LIMIT` to 3 and iterate through the result rows.

```
$sSQLQuery = "SELECT careername FROM careers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";  
$aResult = mysql_query($sSQLQuery);  
while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $sQuoteOfTheDay = $aRow['careername']; 
    echo $sQuoteOfTheDay; 
}
$aResult->free();
```

Don't forget to free `$aResult` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n` is a horror performance killer: it will calculate `RAND()` for **all** rows in the table, then throw away most. Imagine what this does to a table with a million rows.

The best way to do this, is to get the rowcount (e.g. run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;`), then use this value to calculate three indices, then run `SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY primarykey LIMIT $index,1` three times.

The break even for this on a CPU-bound server is at ca. 100 rows!